# Home and End keys only function when holding Ctrl

Tags: windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 Pro on my laptop, home and work computers, however at some point in the last month the home computer Home and End keys only work as expected (that is jumping to the start/end of a line of text) *only* when I hold down the Ctrl key. I'm using a Corsair K65 (10-keyless, without any fancy Fn key overloading stuff). Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. I cam across this because I was having the same issue after leaving for the weekend and coming back to my desk a mess from my cats. I leave my computer on so they must of hit something on my keyboard. After reading a bunch of different answers for help to fix my issue, I figured I should just try the buttons on my keyboard. Going through the F# buttons, I found <kbd>F7</kbd> changed it so that I can use the home and end buttons again.

Answer (score 0):

The usual shortcuts for going to the top and bottom of the document are just Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End.

Only a few situations that we can use separate Home/End key, such as web browser, File Explorer(also can use Ctrl+End).

However, when you are using Notepad, Word, Excel and some other apps, Ctrl+Home and Ctrl+End are common jump method.

Also try it, navigate to

Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Performance > Settings

Uncheck smooth-scroll list boxes

Comment: If I open a .txt file in Notepad++ that's many pages long, and put the cursor in the middle of a line and press End absolutely nothing happens. I have since found that if I hold Shift and End it will highlight from to the end of the line, or Alt and End it will move as you would expect End alone to do. But End alone does nothing at all. (I tried disabling Smooth Scroll, but it still acts the same)